# MassTransit: Domain vs Integration events

Tags: .net, masstransit, mediator

In learning about the Mediator pattern, I came across Mass Transit.
While i have a decent enough understanding of the theory ( i hope) i am struggling to find code samples / documentation that support the scenario below:

Suppose there is **CustomerService (A)** and **NotificationService (B)**.

There are events raised on A that will be exclusively consumed by itself and there are events that will raised by A to be  also consumed by B

In the first scenario imagine a **CustomerUpgradedEvent** is raised and this will be handled internally in the first service. This is what i call domain event and **NewCustomerCreatedEvent** that will also be handled by NotificationService (send emails, etc), which i'm calling integration event.

And herein lies my problem. Should i configure MassTransit to use rabbitMq (or any other out-of-memory bus) for the first kind of events? it seems like an overkill and potentially introducing delays /unnecessary problems (what if connection to queue dies? I know MassTransit has measures to mitigate this but still)

Can i configure MT with both in-memory and rabbitmq and have my targeted dispatching?

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: I concede that there are two questions, 1 is whether this "dual dispatch" is possible and the other is ether MT supports it (which really is a version of the first)  but i don't think your answer is helpful in either direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MassTransit's Mediator can be used alongside a transport-based bus.

Using `IScopedMediator` or `IMediator` will dispatch messages immediately, whereas messages produced via `IPublishEndpoint` or `ISendEndpointProvider` will be dispatched via RabbitMQ (or whatever transport is configured).